# How to correctly code matplotlib’s colormap index in a nested for loop?

Tags: python, matplotlib

**Update with reproducible code:**
I have data in form of numeric values that are stored in a nested dictionary called `dict_data`. This dictionary includes two variables (nested dictionaries), called `ple` and `sampen`. To both variables, three `rois` (lists of data) are attached.

Furthermore, in the nested for loop `for variable in variables: for i in range(3):`, the dictionary’s data is re-stored into a `numpy array` for `ple` and `sampen` respectively
Next, I apply a quick Z transformation on the numpy array data and save the results in yet another and new numpy array called `data_array_z`.

**Here comes my aim:**
I would like to plot a scatterplot for both variables `ple` and `sampen` including their three `rois`(see list `rois` and the dictionary `dict_data`). Additionally, I would like to plot linear regression lines across the datapoints in the three `rois`. An image at the end shows the result that is reproducible with this code. All this works so far.

**Problem:**
I would like to apply matplotlib’s `colormap` for both variables’ scatter points and their regression lines. I do not understand how to code the `c=` or `color=` commands so that matplotlib plots each new point and regression line with an individual color from a specified colormap, such as `tab20c_r`.

Currently I receive the following error. `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'`

Here is my full code for overview:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats

# Data
rois = ["interoception", "exteroception", "cognitive"]
variables = ["ple", "sampen"]

dict_data = {
    "ple":
    {"interoception": [-1.10037122285797, -1.12865588460383, -0.703950853686781],
     "exteroception": [-1.17398360636007, -1.3990001171012, -1.04528124479161],
     "cognitive": [-1.41360171989828, -1.40283540165903, -0.97942989571082]},
     "sampen":
    {"interoception": [0.949609993391806, 0.855956231042865, 0.960562761361569],
     "exteroception": [0.910728054043017, 0.800209085753256, 0.884463613744541],
     "cognitive": [0.832925242590743, 0.782835997734383, 0.899277318610028]},
    }


# Linear regression for each subject and variable across the three regions
x_pos_1 = np.array([0, 1, 2])
x_pos_2 = np.array([3, 4, 5])

for variable in variables:
    for i in range(3):
        data_array = np.array([
            dict_data[variable]["interoception"][i],
            dict_data[variable]["exteroception"][i],
            dict_data[variable]["cognitive"][i]
            ])

        # Z normalization
        data_array_z = []
        for i in data_array:
            z = (i - np.mean(data_array)) / np.std(data_array)
            data_array_z.append(z)
        
        # Plot
        cmap = plt.get_cmap("tab20c_r")
        segment_cmap = cmap(np.linspace(0, 1, len(data_array_z)))

        if variable == "ple":
            reg = sp.stats.linregress(x_pos_1, data_array_z)
            plt.scatter(x_pos_1, data_array_z, color=segment_cmap[data_array.index(i)])
            plt.plot(x_pos_1, reg[1] + reg[0]*x_pos_1,
                     linestyle="-", linewidth=1, color=segment_cmap[data_array.index(i)],
                zorder=2)

        elif variable == "sampen":
            reg = sp.stats.linregress(x_pos_2, data_array_z)
            plt.scatter(x_pos_2, data_array_z)
            plt.plot(x_pos_2, reg[1] + reg[0]*x_pos_2,
                     linestyle="-", linewidth=1, zorder=2)
plt.show()
```

This is what the result looks like when removing the codeline `color=segment_cmap[data_array.index(i)]` from the first plot, so that matplotlib simply takes its default colormap.

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [complete and reproducibel](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example of your problem. Also, `data_array` seems to be a numpy array. But numpy arrays do not have an `index` method.

Comment: `segment_cmap = cmap(np.linspace(0, 1, len(data_array)))` is an array but `data_array.index(i)` is not necessarily an integer so I'd expect `segment_cmap[data_array.index(i)])` to throw an index error as the access operator for lists `[]` is only defined for integer values and slices, but as @MaxPowers says it doesn't seem like the error you're getting corresponds to the code you're sharing.

Comment: Thanks. I fully updated the code and my explanation of the problem. The code can now be copy-pasted and reproduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has two problems.

1. You reuse the name `i` in an inner loop, when the inner loop is completed `i` is now a float, not an index into the columns of your data.
2. You had this idea of choosing the colors from a qualitative color map, but by default Matplotlib uses colors from a qualitative color map, you have just to use them.

Re ①, I changed the name of the inner loop variable, re ② I used a cycler object to go through the colors from the `tab20c_r` color map — I used 3 colors, per your code, but the colors are repeated in the plot, is this what you want?

Further, I've added a legend.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import linregress
from cycler import cycler

# Data
rois = ["interoception", "exteroception", "cognitive"]
variables = ["ple", "sampen"]

dict_data = {
    "ple":
    {"interoception": [-1.10037122285797, -1.12865588460383, -0.703950853686781],
     "exteroception": [-1.17398360636007, -1.3990001171012, -1.04528124479161],
     "cognitive": [-1.41360171989828, -1.40283540165903, -0.97942989571082]},
     "sampen":
    {"interoception": [0.949609993391806, 0.855956231042865, 0.960562761361569],
     "exteroception": [0.910728054043017, 0.800209085753256, 0.884463613744541],
     "cognitive": [0.832925242590743, 0.782835997734383, 0.899277318610028]},
    }


# Linear regression for each subject and variable across the three regions
x_pos_1 = np.array([0, 1, 2])
x_pos_2 = np.array([3, 4, 5])

plt.gca().set_prop_cycle(
    cycler(color=plt.get_cmap("tab20c_r")(np.linspace(0, 1, 3))))

for variable in variables:
    for i in range(3):

        data_array = np.array([
            dict_data[variable]["interoception"][i],
            dict_data[variable]["exteroception"][i],
            dict_data[variable]["cognitive"][i]
            ])

        # Z normalization
        data_array_z = []
        for y in data_array:
            z = (y - np.mean(data_array)) / np.std(data_array)
            data_array_z.append(z)
        
        # Plot
        if variable == "ple" or variable == "acw":
            reg = linregress(x_pos_1, data_array_z)
            print(i)
            plt.scatter(x_pos_1, data_array_z, **color, label="%s, %s"%(variable, i+1))
            plt.plot(x_pos_1, reg[1] + reg[0]*x_pos_1,
                     linestyle="-", linewidth=1)

        elif variable == "sampen":
            reg = linregress(x_pos_2, data_array_z)
            plt.scatter(x_pos_2, data_array_z, label="%s, %s"%(variable, i+1))
            plt.plot(x_pos_2, reg[1] + reg[0]*x_pos_2,
                     linestyle="-", linewidth=1, zorder=2)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks. I see, actually the solution to my problem is easier than I thought. What you coded is correct, since I wanted the colors (the color cycle) to repeat again from zero for the next (```sampen```) plotting after the the first (```ple```) plotting is completed. Hence, the points of the scatterplots, e.g., the first plotted point of ```ple```, should have the same color as the first plotted point of ```sampen```. And thats exactly what your code does as I understand it.

Comment: @Philipp _"[…] the solution to my problem is easier than I thought"_ — I made a little edit and now it's even simpler!